# Fetching rows whose value is given which lies between two rows with given condition

Tags: mysql

I have mysql schema with values

**Sample Schema and data**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `items` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemtype` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

       insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('1','APPLE','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('2','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('3','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('4','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('5','APPLE','1','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('6','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('7','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('8','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('9','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('10','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('11','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('12','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('13','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('14','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('15','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('16','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('17','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('18','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('19','APPLE','1','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('20','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('21','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('22','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('23','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('24','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('25','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('26','APPLE','1','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('27','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('28','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('29','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('30','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('31','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('32','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('33','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('34','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('35','APPLE','1','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('36','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('37','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('38','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('39','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('40','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('41','APPLE','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('42','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('43','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('44','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('45','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('46','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('47','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('48','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('49','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('50','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('51','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('52','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('53','APPLE','1','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('54','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('55','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('56','MANGO','0','FM1010');
insert into `products` (`id`, `items`, `itemtype`, `category`) values('57','APPLE','1','FM1010');
```

**PROBLEM**

Requirement is that i need to fetch id of all the rows where `item=APPLE` and `itemtype=1` which lies between the rows which has `item=APPLE, itemtype=0` and `item=APPLE, itemtype=1`

So in example data, between `id=5` (Apple,1) and 'id=41' (Apple,0), there are 3 rows which has items APPLE with item type 1 (row with ids 19, 26 and 35).

Similarly between `id=41` (Apple,0)  and `id=57` (Apple,1), there are again 2 rows which has items APPLE with item type 1 (row with ids 45 and 53).

So the required output ids are 19,26,35,45,53

**UPDATE**

Explanation

> The first boundary is row with id 1 (Apple,0), to find next boundary
>   the row should be APPLE,1, in this case row with id 5. Now between 1
>   and 5 there is no Apple,1 so we ignore this.
>
> Now we take row id 5 (Apple,1) as a first boundary, the next boundary
>   should be row with APPLE,0, which is row 41.
>
> Now we have 3 rows with APPLE,1 between these two. 19,26 and 35
>
> now first boundary is 41 Apple,0, now next boundary should be APPLE,1
>   which is row id 53.  between these two there is no APPLE,1 , so we ignore it
>
> So final result should be 19,26,35

There are several data, we have to match all APPLE, 1 between APPLE,0 and APPLE,1

**UPDATED**
I have modified the schema and the problem

Comment: why not last (APPLE,1) ?

Comment: @McNets, Didn't get you?

Comment: I've got it. Just curiosity.

Comment: I don't understand. You want everything between 5 (0) and 41 (1) but also between 41 (0) and 57 (1), so the 0 and 1 as boundaries are exchangeable? Then why not getting 5,19 and 26, which lie between 1 (0) and 35 (1)?

Comment: @StefanoZanini, between 5 (Apple,1) and 41 (Apple,0) => 19,26,35 (All Apple,1)
and
between 41 (Apple,0) and 57 (Apple,1) => 45,53  (All Apple,1)
So the actual output should be 19,26,35,45,53

Comment: I understood that, but the definition of the rows you want is somehow ambiguous. If it is **"all rows in groups whose boundaries are either (Apple, 1) as lower and (Apple, 0) as upper OR (Apple, 0) as lower and (Apple, 1) as upper"** then another group satisfies this definition. Have I misinterpreted the definition of the requirements?

Comment: @StefanoZanini, The boundaries could either be between (Apple,1) and (Apple,0) OR between (Apple, 0) and (Apple,1), whatever may be boundaries between these two, we fetch All (Apple,1) between the boundaries

Comment: This doesn't match with the expected output you wrote, because 5, 19, 26, 35 are between ID 1 (Apple, 0) and ID 41 (Apple 1), yet your example is not listing 5 as expected result.

Comment: Between ID 1 and Id 5, there is no Apple,1, so we ignore this boundary, now we check from id 5 and 41, but here we have 3 Apple,1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138946/discussion-between-stefano-zanini-and-watsmyname).

Comment: You also need to explain what "between" means. Rows in SQL tables have no inherent order. Is the "between" and the order supposed to be based on `product (id)` values or something else?

Comment: And the row with `id=45` is not 'Apple'. It's 'Mango'.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Actually records are ordered by `id`. And we need to pick all rows where `item=Apple` and `itemtype= 1` (for simplicity lets say Apple,1) which lies between Apple,0 and Apple,1 (or Apple,1 and Apple,0). For e.g
-1. row id 1 (Apple,0) & row id 5 (Apple,1), There are no Apple,1 rows between these two rows, so we ignore it.
-2. Next row id 5 (Apple,1) & row id 41 (Apple,0). There are 3  Apple,1 rows between them. The rows are 19,26 & 35
-3. Next row id 41 (Apple,0) & row id 57 (Apple,1). There's only 1 Apple,1 between them, The row with id 53

The final result => 19,26,35 & 53

Comment: The description is still a bit vague. And doesn't match the data in the question (which has still 45 in the wanted output). Correct the question please. All the relevant information should be in the question, not in comments.

Comment: This part looks inconsistent: *"Next row id 41 (Apple,0) & row id 57 (Apple,1)."* Why isn't 41 (Apple, 0) and 53 (Apple,1)? 53 is before 57.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, yes you are right, that was a mistake, i have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE items = 'apple'
AND itemtype = '1'
AND id > 
    (
        SELECT MIN(id) AS id
        FROM products
        WHERE items = 'apple'
        AND itemtype = '1'
    )
AND id < 
    (
        SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM products
        WHERE items = 'apple'
        AND itemtype = '0'
        AND id > 
            (
                SELECT MIN(id) AS id
                FROM products
                WHERE items = 'apple'
                AND itemtype = '1'
            )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, it partially work, it doesn't fetches rows 45,53 between 41 and 57, see my updated schema