# Fetch rows of two set of ids each, having given condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This is similar to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001133/fetching-rows-whose-value-is-given-which-lies-between-two-rows-with-given-condit), but now I have change in the requirement, so I am posting as a new question.

I have following sql schema and the sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Command varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  Type tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38561128,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38561099,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38561098,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38541192,'ABCD',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540956,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540955,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540816,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540815,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540814,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540776,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540774,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540772,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540605,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540461,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540460,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540459,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540418,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540417,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540223,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540222,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540112,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540077,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540039,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38540021,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539928,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539715,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539501,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539500,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539499,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539498,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539497,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539496,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539450,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539449,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539448,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539217,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539171,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38539170,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538965,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538883,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538852,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538632,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538476,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538475,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538474,'HIJK',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538473,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538472,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538471,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538470,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538469,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538468,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538467,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538419,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538418,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538417,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538416,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538415,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538413,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538244,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538243,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538242,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538022,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538021,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538020,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538019,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38538018,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537750,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537749,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537564,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537516,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537460,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537346,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38537185,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536927,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536925,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536924,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536887,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536886,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536885,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536806,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536805,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536804,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536802,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536774,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536771,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536770,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536367,'HIJK',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536366,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536342,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536208,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536207,'HIJK',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536206,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536205,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536162,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38536161,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38520155,'ABCD',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519878,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519877,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519876,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519823,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519822,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519783,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519782,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519781,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38519306,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518736,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518735,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518562,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518462,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518409,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518221,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518220,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518067,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518066,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518065,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518064,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518063,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518062,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518061,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518060,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38518059,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517976,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517975,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517974,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517973,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517972,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517971,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517538,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517537,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517536,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517480,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38517479,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513858,'ABCD',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513528,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513527,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513286,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513220,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513219,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513157,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513156,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38513154,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38512360,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38512160,'HIJK',3);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511976,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511749,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511748,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511746,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511744,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511743,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511742,'ABCD',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511741,'HIJK',1);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511691,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511690,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511689,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511405,'PQRS',0);
INSERT INTO items (id,Command,Type) values(38511404,'ABCD',1);
```

Lets say the rows are ordered in ascending order

I need  rows of two set of ids each, where the one being `Command=ABCD, Type=0` and other being `Command=ABCD, Type=1`

So from sample data following should be the final result.

```
38511404,38513858 (Type 1, Type 0)
38513858,38517536 (Type 0, Type 1)
38517536,38520155 (Type 1, Type 0)
38520155,38536205 (Type 0, Type 1)
38536205,38541192 (Type 1, Type 0)
38541192,38561128 (Type 0, Type 1)
```

We should have same result if the rows are descending order (but the order of the resulting row might be different)

This is what i tried, but its not giving desired output

```
SELECT 
  id,
  lastid,
  Command 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    id,
    Command,
    Type,
    @last_id AS lastid,
    @last_type AS lastType,
    @last_id := id,
    @last_type := Type
  FROM
    items,
    (SELECT 
      @last_id := 0,
      @last_type := 0) SQLVars 
  WHERE Command = 'ABCD' 
  ORDER BY id ASC,
    id) a 
WHERE ((a.Type = 0  AND a.lastType = 1) 
OR (a.Type = 1 AND a.lastType = 0))
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: This is only the description of your requirements. There is no question, no demonstration of own efforts.

Comment: @Shadow I have updated the question with what I have tried, but this didn't work